# Bootstrap and distribution of the test statistic

Tags: bootstrap, rule-of-thumb

One rule of thumb says that we should avoid using the bootstrap to construct a confidence interval for some test statistic, if (1) the test statistic is greatly affected by outliers or by rare elements of the population, (2) the sample size is very small, or (3) the distribution of the test statistic is not roughly bell shaped.

Are these rules of thumb good suggestions?  If so, how important is part (3) of this rule of thumb?  What happens if this doesn't hold?  Are there examples where (1)+(2) hold but (3) doesn't, and where the bootstrap goes badly awry?

Comment: Where did these rules come from?

Comment: @Glen_b, from a colleague.  I will edit my question to ask if they are correct.  Note they were characterized as rules of thumb, rather than strict rules.